# 8 bit shifter -VHDL

Tags: vhdl, bit-shift

I am trying to use xilinx tools to define and simulate an 8-bit shifter in VHDL that can shift or rotate left or right by 0,1,2 or 3 bit positions. I'm trying to implement this on a digilent basys 2 board.

I am just beginning to learn vhdl programming. Can anyone please help?
Can anyone show me what the vhdl code should look like?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. Add to that that there are massive ammounts of tutorials online. Just search for it.

Answer (score 3):

shift and rotate functionality can be found in numeric_std package. below is some sample code as starting point:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;


entity EXAMPLE is
Port ( 
    clk : in  STD_LOGIC; -- master clock
    enable : in std_logic; -- when '1' --> rotate
    dir : in  STD_LOGIC; -- when '1': right, when '0': left
    nr : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0); -- number of steps to rotate
    din : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0); -- in vector
    dout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0)); -- out vector
end EXAMPLE;

architecture Behavioral of EXAMPLE is

begin

shifter: process(clk)
begin
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      if enable='1' then
         if dir='0' then -- right
            dout<=std_logic_vector(rotate_right(unsigned(din),to_integer(unsigned(nr))));
         else -- left
            dout<=std_logic_vector(rotate_left(unsigned(din), to_integer(unsigned(nr))));
         end if;
      end if;

    end if;
 end process shifter;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
Rotate Right = bitvector(0) & bitvector(7 downto 1);
<br>Rotate Left = bitvector(6 downto 0) & bitvector(7);
```

Use concatenation as other functions are not synthesize-able.

Answer (score 1):

Use the functions designed for the purpose in the [`ieee.numeric_std` library](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/numeric_std.vhdl).

Use (or cast) your input of the appropriate `signed` or `unsigned` vector type.

---

Here's the "prototypes" of those functions so you can see what you are getting.

```
 --============================================================================
  -- Shift and Rotate Functions
  --============================================================================

  -- Id: S.1
  function SHIFT_LEFT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: UNSIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
  -- Result: Performs a shift-left on an UNSIGNED vector COUNT times.
  --         The vacated positions are filled with '0'.
  --         The COUNT leftmost elements are lost.

  -- Id: S.2
  function SHIFT_RIGHT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: UNSIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
  -- Result: Performs a shift-right on an UNSIGNED vector COUNT times.
  --         The vacated positions are filled with '0'.
  --         The COUNT rightmost elements are lost.

  -- Id: S.3
  function SHIFT_LEFT (ARG: SIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return SIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: SIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
  -- Result: Performs a shift-left on a SIGNED vector COUNT times.
  --         The vacated positions are filled with '0'.
  --         The COUNT leftmost elements are lost.

  -- Id: S.4
  function SHIFT_RIGHT (ARG: SIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return SIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: SIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
  -- Result: Performs a shift-right on a SIGNED vector COUNT times.
  --         The vacated positions are filled with the leftmost
  --         element, ARG'LEFT. The COUNT rightmost elements are lost.

  --============================================================================

  -- Id: S.5
  function ROTATE_LEFT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: UNSIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
  -- Result: Performs a rotate-left of an UNSIGNED vector COUNT times.

  -- Id: S.6
  function ROTATE_RIGHT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: UNSIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
  -- Result: Performs a rotate-right of an UNSIGNED vector COUNT times.

  -- Id: S.7
  function ROTATE_LEFT (ARG: SIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return SIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: SIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
  -- Result: Performs a logical rotate-left of a SIGNED
  --         vector COUNT times.

  -- Id: S.8
  function ROTATE_RIGHT (ARG: SIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return SIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: SIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
  -- Result: Performs a logical rotate-right of a SIGNED
  --         vector COUNT times.
```